# How can I filter out important messages in WhatsApp when it arrives?

Tags: whatsapp

I belong to a WhatsApp group, but the group members post unwanted messages every minute. I want to be a member of this group and receive only some important messages.

1. How can I be a member of this group still and block all the messages?
2. How can I filter out messages like "IMPORTANT" and read only those?

Comment: It's not clear if this question is about the mobile app or the web application.

Comment: Phone, Tablet and Web.

Comment: Those details should be included on the question. It's worth to say that mobile apps are offtopic on this site and that including all the a variants make the question too broad, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way is for the members of the group to write the words "important message" as the headline or anywhere of the message before submitting it. When you want to find those messages again, you can open the group chat, tap the options on the upper right and tap "Search" then input the words, "important message". And it will highlight the words while enable you to select "next" and "previous" to find other important messages.

In order to do this ask the members to do exactly as said in the beginning. Tag, or write "important message" as headline.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation and created a new group, people posted the important messages there.